# Abrir link com outro navegador

Tags: php, redirecionamento

Olá, tenho um programa que só abre no IE, mas nem todo cliente acessa seus documentos por ele. Gostaria de saber se tem como, quando o cliente apertasse o botão de inicializar ele redirecionaria para abrir o link no IE.

O programa não e meu por isso não posso postar parte dele.

```
system("cmd /C 
Start
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"https://www.link.com.br/
EXIT");
```

Tentei desta maneira mas não deu certo.

Comment: Por `PHP` isso é impossível, mesmo que fosse por `Javascript` por questões de segurança, eu não entendi bem sua dúvida por que você usou essa tag. Então o programa em questão é linha de comando ou PHP?

Comment: Em PHP, mas li em um fórum que dava pra fazer utilizando este código.

Comment: Poderia apontar a fonte? Só pra constar PHP é Back-End, ou seja, o que acontece é do lado do servidor, seria mais plausivel fazer por Javascript que é Front-End, e mesmo assim a segurança impede. Poderia explicar exatamente o que esse software que o seu amigo está fazendo faz, é um navegador voltado pra empresa?

Comment: Sim. Pelo que ele me disse o arquivo faz muitas requisições e depois entra em uma página de download. Na hora deste download não dá pra baixar pelo Chrome e nem pelo Firefox. Os únicos que conseguem fazer o download e o IE e o opera.

Comment: A fonte? O tal fórum?

Comment: http://www.hardware.com.br/comunidade/abrir-link/1465953/

Comment: Desculpa a demora, eu li a conversa do link só agora, então, a maioria ali não parece saber do que está falando. O melhor seria bloquear a página pelo `useragent` assim impedindo que o cliente use outro navegador que não o IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só conheço um método que force o usuário a usar o navegador padrão.
No seu site você vai ter que por o código javascript que verifique o navegador usado, se ele for IE de qualquer versão não fará nada, se for qualquer outro navegador vai redirecionar.

```
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
if (msie < 1){
   window.location.href = "naoeie.html";
}
```

Se quiser que verifique apenas após carregar a página o código deverá ser uma função chamada por `onload`:

```
window.onload = function(){checkMsie()}

function checkMsie(){
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
    if (msie < 1){
       window.location.href = "naoeie.html";
    }
}
```

Sendo o nome do arquivo naoeie.html apenas um exemplo, nessa página você vai colocar as instruções pro cliente sempre abrir pelo IE.

Agora se preferir fazer por PHP o código seria assim:

```
<?php
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(!preg_match('/(MSIE|Trident)/i',$ua)){
   echo "Você não está usando internet explorer";
   exit(); //Para o carregamento da página
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Bem vindo ao meu site!</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      CONTEÚDO DO SEU SITE PARA INTERNET EXPLORER
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado. Vou utilizar aqui.

Comment: Espero que tenha resolvido